# Google Drive API - DriveQuickStart sample not working

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to connect my app to Google drive.So first I tried samples.I followed the [Google drive tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android).First it ask to select the account and allow to take picture through camera and after that nothing happens(simply white screen).No toast displayed.I debugged and the it stopped at

```
        File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
```

Here I have given my sample

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1;
  static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 2;
  static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 3;
  public static File f;
  private static Uri fileUri;
  private static Drive service;
  private GoogleAccountCredential credential;
  private Bitmap mPhoto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
        startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
        String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        if (accountName != null) {
          credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
          service = getDriveService(credential);
          startCameraIntent();
        }
      }
      break;
    case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        saveFileToDrive();
      } else {
        startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
      }
      break;
    case CAPTURE_IMAGE:
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          getContentResolver().notifyChange(fileUri, null);

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            try {

                mPhoto = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                        .getBitmap(cr, fileUri);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        saveFileToDrive();
      }
    }
  }

  private void startCameraIntent() {
      Intent c = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
      String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
        java.io.File f = new java.io.File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                 "abc-" + timeStamp
                        + ".jpg");
        Log.e("FILE", f.getAbsolutePath());
        c.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        fileUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

      startActivityForResult(c, CAPTURE_IMAGE);


  }

 private void saveFileToDrive() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            try {
              // File's binary content
              java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
              FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", fileContent);

              // File's metadata.
              File body = new File();
              body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
              body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");

              File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
              if (file != null) {
                showToast("Photo uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
                startCameraIntent();
              }
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
              startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        });
        t.start();
      }

 private Drive getDriveService(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential)
            .build();
      }

 public void showToast(final String toast) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        });
      }
```

}

stopped at *service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();* and getting warning as *vfy unable to resolve static field* No error but nothing happened.Any suggestion please..

the logcat stack trace is as follows

```
08-05 14:38:07.029: W/KeyCharacterMap(10792): Can't open keycharmap file
08-05 14:38:07.029: W/KeyCharacterMap(10792): Error loading keycharmap file
08-05 14:38:07.029: W/KeyCharacterMap(10792): Using default keymap
08-05 14:38:27.989: W/AbstractGoogleClient(10962): Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
08-05 14:38:42.729: W/dalvikvm(10962): VFY: unable to resolve static field 685 (auth_client_play_services_err_notification_msg) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
08-05 14:38:42.879: W/dalvikvm(10962): VFY: unable to resolve static field 694 (common_google_play_services_install_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
08-05 14:38:42.879: W/dalvikvm(10962): VFY: unable to resolve static field 690 (common_google_play_services_enable_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
08-05 14:38:42.889: W/dalvikvm(10962): VFY: unable to resolve static field 700 (common_google_play_services_update_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
08-05 14:38:42.889: W/dalvikvm(10962): VFY: unable to resolve static field 697 (common_google_play_services_unsupported_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
08-05 14:38:42.889: W/dalvikvm(10962): VFY: unable to resolve static field 691 (common_google_play_services_install_button) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
08-05 14:38:42.899: W/dalvikvm(10962): VFY: unable to resolve static field 688 (common_google_play_services_enable_button) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
08-05 14:38:42.899: W/dalvikvm(10962): VFY: unable to resolve static field 698 (common_google_play_services_update_button) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
08-05 14:38:42.899: W/dalvikvm(10962): VFY: unable to resolve static field 695 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
08-05 14:38:42.899: W/dalvikvm(10962): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 10
```

Comment: Please add a stack trace.

Comment: @BurcuDogan I have added stack trace

Comment: I have the same issue!  I've been trying to fix this issue by adding/removing *.jar files into the build path, but did not have much success.  I get the same errors mentioned above.  In addition, when I try to save the picture to the Google Drive, I get the following errors in the Log Cat<br/>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden <br/>{"Code 403" "errors": ...}<br/>"message": "Access Not Configured"  I followed the steps in the following tutorial:  [basic links](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android).